# Generated queries contain redundant products?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have rather simple models like these:

```
TableA2TableB = Table('TableA2TableB', Base.metadata,
                        Column('tablea_id', BigInteger, ForeignKey('TableA.id')),
                        Column('tableb_id', Integer, ForeignKey('TableB.id')))


class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TableA'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    infohash = Column(String, unique=True)
    url = Column(String)
    tablebs = relationship('TableB', secondary=TableA2TableB, backref='tableas')


class TableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TableB'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String, unique=True)
```

However, sqla generates queries like

```
SELECT "TableB".id, "TableB".url AS "TableB_url" FROM "TableB", "TableA2TableB" 
WHERE "TableA2TableB".tableb_id = "TableB".id AND "TableA2TableB".tablea_id = 408997;
```

But why is there a cartesian product in the query when the attributes selected are those in `TableB`? `TableA2TableB` shouldn't be needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is right now, there is a backref relationship in TableB (tableas) and it's loaded because the default loading mode is set to select.

You may want to change the TableA.tablebs to

```
tablebs = relationship('TableB', secondary=TableA2TableB, backref='tableas', lazy="dynamic")
```

Comment: But, even without `lazy="dynamic"`, how is the backref loaded when it's only selecting `"TableB".id` and `"TableB".url`? There's nothing being collected from `TableA2TableB`.

Comment: The query you posted seems to be coming from something like  session.query(TableB).filter(TableB.tableas.id==408997) so it must be referenced somehow. By specificing lazy="dynamic" and doing something like session.query(TableB).filter(TableB.id==xxxxx) you won't have the second table used in your query